# Prove that the series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to prove wether the following series converges or diverges.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{n^3 - n}}$$
However, I'm only allowed to use the definition of a series, the geometric series test, or the divergence test since that is what we have been thaught so far. I can't see any dramatic cancellation so proving by definition doesn't seem to work, divergence test is inconclusive since $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} a_n = 0$
, and there is no obvious ratio for the geometric series test. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: GS test? Geometric series test?

Comment: What do you mean by “divergence case”?

Comment: I assumed test for divergence was intended.

Comment: Hint: $n^3 - n > n^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n^3-n}$

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^N-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{0.5}{(n+1)}+\frac{0.5}{(n-1)}$

$(-\frac{1}{2}+\color{red}{\frac{0.5}{3}}+\frac{0.5}{1})+(\color{red}{-\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{0.5}{4}+\frac{0.5}{2})+(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{0.5}{5}+\color{red}{\frac{0.5}{3}})+\dots + (-\frac{1}{N}+\frac{0.5}{N+1}+\frac{0.5}{N-1})$

The terms pictured in red cancel each other out.  Similarly, the terms with denominator $4$ will all cancel each other out, and so too will the terms with denominator $5$ and so on.  The series "telescopes" and the only terms that remain will be those that didn't cancel from the beginning and those who didn't cancel from the end.

$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{0.5}{1}+\frac{0.5}{2}+\frac{0.5}{N}-\frac{1}{N}+\frac{0.5}{N+1}$

As $N\to \infty$ these last few terms can be ignored, leaving the final sum equal to:

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-n}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: +1 but you should really write $1/2$ rather than $0.5$ when you want the exact value of that rational number.

Comment: @EthanBolker I intentionally wrote such that the denominators went $1,2,3,4,\dots$ and not have the multiplication by two in the denominator.  I intentionally wrote $0.5$ in the numerator so as to not encourage wanting to rewrite $\frac{1/2}{n+1}$ as $\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$ and to avoid writing a fraction in the numerator as I find it looks worse.  Regardless, it should be obvious that $-1+0.5+0.5=0$ whether written with fractions or otherwise.

Comment: I understand your good reasons. My personal preference is to discourage decimal representations for common fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$${1\over n^3-n}={1\over 2}\left [{1\over n(n-1)}-{1\over (n+1)n}\right ]$$
Hence $$\sum_{n=2}^N{1\over n^3-n}={1\over 2}\left [ {1\over 2}-{1\over (N+1)N}\right ]$$